# Move pagebreak up or down depending on hidden or unhidden rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with VBA code to hide or unhide a bunch of rows depending on if we need those or not. The problem is that when we hide the rows, we are printing a bunch of half empty pages. Is there a way to dynamically change the pagebreaks depending on if the rows are hidden or not?

Edit: Pref without VBA

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can copy only the non hide  cells to another sheet with:

On the Home tab, in the Editing group, click Find & Select, and then click Go To.

In the Go To dialog box, click Special.

Under Select, click Visible cells only, and then click OK.

On the Home tab, in the Clipboard group, click Copy